# Login to web page and parse data

Tags: node.js

There is a website, which is using HTML Login form for authenticating with username/password. I need to write NodeJS application which would login to that web site, navigate to certain link and extract data. The part of navigation is clear, I can probably use cheerio to find elements. But it's not clear which framework to use for login. Are there any modules which will make it simple submitting simple forms and store the cookies?

Comment: You can use `request` module to send login request(API call) and get the token and access website with that token.

Comment: But I don't want to invent cookie manager

Answer (score 0):

use **nightmare** : https://www.npmjs.com/package/nightmare

here is just example :

you can click submit button

```
const Nightmare = require('nightmare')
const nightmare = Nightmare({ show: true })

nightmare
  .goto('https://duckduckgo.com')
  .type('#search_form_input_homepage', 'github nightmare')
  .click('#search_button_homepage')
  .wait('#r1-0 a.result__a')
  .evaluate(() => document.querySelector('#r1-0 a.result__a').href)
  .end()
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(error => {
    console.error('Search failed:', error)
  })
```

you can set cookie

```
nightmare
  .goto('http://google.com')
  .cookies.set({
    name: 'token',
    value: 'some token',
    path: '/query',
    secure: true
  })
  // ... other actions ...
  .then(() => {
    // ...
  })
```

Comment: so it will open some window, loading all images and resources that comes with the page. This is overkill for my task. I was seeking something which will just use network connection to the specified url and leave it to me which resource to download. Just take care of authentication/cookies.